# Is there a way to style a class only if an aria-label in a different element is set to a value?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to style a class only if an `aria-label` in a different element is set to a value?

Here's an example:

```css
[aria-label*="Offline"] {
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.text { /* is there a way to only make this happen if aria-label="Offline" without changing the html? */
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="user">
    <div class="status">
        <div aria-label="Offline">Offline</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="name">
            <div class="text">Name</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you not open to using JavaScript?

Comment: i would be, but unfortunately i can only use css for this

Comment: With the current html nesting I dont think it is, because there is no parent selector in CSS

Comment: damn it. okay, thanks lol